# Windows (Forms) Application Project Suggestion

Tags: windows, winforms, project, recommendation-engine

I will start working on a Project soon, and as I am a noob in regards to coding (and general indecisiveness due to the lack of knowledge), I would like to have some suggestions in regards to what type of Windows (forms) application I should build (eg. payroll system, library system, etc)

I know there are a lot of ideas out there, but I would like some suggestions of an easy system to build, including a system that is easy to expand on. Will also make use of a database (connecting SQL Server to the application)

I will be using .NET / C# (VS)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience 90% of the commercial systems I've been hired to write just involve relatively basic storage and manipulation of data with some layers of security around access. 
Maybe start with something like a payroll system, but keep in the back of your mind that you could scale to accommodate a full HRMIS (Human Resources Management Information System). Also, experiment with ASP.NET MVC and Web Technologies, in my experience, the majority of systems now are moving to a web-based implementation.

The possibilities are endless in the world of software development.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a winforms program that calculates all the primenumbers between two user inputs. You could also then output these to a XML-file, and make a button that lets the user open an XML-file and reload whatever they input back then.

It's pretty simple, but still involves some Winforms basics and some XML data storage/manipulation.